# Autofac Configuration - How do I convert Code Section to Autofac Config

Tags: config, autofac, named, configurationsection

I am building Autofac Container as below

```
_container = ConfigureContainer(new ContainerBuilder()).Build();
```

I have ConfigureContainer method to build/configure Autofac ContainerBuilder as below

```
        private static ContainerBuilder ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder cb)
        {
            cb.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
            cb.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacJobsModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

            cb.Register(l => Logging.Logger.Instance()).As<ILogger>();

            var reader = new ConfigurationSettingsReader();
            cb.RegisterModule(reader);

            // How do I convert following lines to Autofac Config?

            cb.RegisterCollection<StandardTask>("IList<StandardTask>").As<IList<StandardTask>>();

            cb.RegisterType<HealthMonitoringMessageDispatcherTask>().Named<StandardTask>("HealthMonitoringTask1").MemberOf("IList<StandardTask>");
            cb.RegisterType<HealthMonitoringMessageDispatcherTask>().Named<StandardTask>("HealthMonitoringTask2").MemberOf("IList<StandardTask>");

            cb.RegisterType<PurgeMessageDispatcherTask>().Named<StandardTask>("PurgeTask1");
            cb.RegisterType<PurgeMessageDispatcherTask>().Named<StandardTask>("PurgeTask2");

            return cb;
        }
```

I have Autofac configuration section as below

```
<autofac>
    <components>
      <!--<component type="NAB.Custom.Logging.Logger, NAB.Custom.Logging" service="NAB.Logging.Core.ILogger, NAB.Logging" />-->
      <component type="NAB.Windows.ServicesConsole.Services.SchedulerService, NAB.Windows.ServicesConsole" service="NAB.Windows.ServicesConsole.Services.Core.ITopshelfService, NAB.Windows.ServicesConsole" />
      <component type="NAB.Windows.ServicesConsole.Jobs.HealthMonitoringMessageDispatcherJob, NAB.Windows.ServicesConsole" />
      <component type="NAB.Windows.ServicesConsole.Jobs.PurgeMessageDispatcherJob, NAB.Windows.ServicesConsole" />
    </components>
  </autofac>
```

It resolves the configured component from the Custom Configuration Section correctly, but, I want to move following registrations from code to Custom Configuration Section as well, where I am unable to find proper solution for...

```
            // How do I convert following lines to Autofac Config?

            cb.RegisterCollection<StandardTask>("IList<StandardTask>").As<IList<StandardTask>>();

            cb.RegisterType<HealthMonitoringMessageDispatcherTask>().Named<StandardTask>("HealthMonitoringTask1").MemberOf("IList<StandardTask>");
            cb.RegisterType<HealthMonitoringMessageDispatcherTask>().Named<StandardTask>("HealthMonitoringTask2").MemberOf("IList<StandardTask>");

            cb.RegisterType<PurgeMessageDispatcherTask>().Named<StandardTask>("PurgeTask1");
            cb.RegisterType<PurgeMessageDispatcherTask>().Named<StandardTask>("PurgeTask2");
```

Any suggestions? Little code snippet will be very useful. Basically I am registering **named** collection and then injecting components to the collection which is constructor parameter of one of my registered objects.

Comment: Wich version of *Autofac* are you using ? `RegisterCollection` is deprecated since version 2. `IEnumerable<T>` is always resolvable and will include all registered components for service `T`. The following documentation may help you see how to use collection with autofac http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation on how configuration works in Autofac is here.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html) Unless you're on the 4.0 beta, you're probably looking at the [3.x XML configuration style](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html#configuring-with-application-configuration-legacy).

You figured out component registrations. To add a key/name to a registration, just add that attribute.

```
<component type="Service"
           service="IService"
           name="the-key-goes-here" />
```

There is no XML configuration support for named collections. If you're stuck using them and can't move to just `IEnumerable<T>` then it's best if you just leave those in a module and register the module via configuration.

```
<modules>
  <module type="MyModule" />
</modules>
```